# Compute the Wronskian. Abel's formula and determinant difference.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

This question is not about solving the ODE, but about understanding something about the Wronskian and Abel's formula.

Given the equation:

$y''-\frac{3}{x}y'+\frac{5}{x^2}y=3$

I get:

$y_1=x^2\cos \left(\ln \left(x\right)\right)$

$y_2=x^2\sin \left(\ln \left(x\right)\right)$

$y_1'=2x\cos \left(\ln \left(x\right)\right)-x\sin \left(\ln \left(x\right)\right)$

$y_2'=2x\sin \left(\ln \left(x\right)\right)+x\cos \left(\ln \left(x\right)\right)$

Computing the Wronskian with denterminant I get:

$W\left(x_1,x_2\right)=\det\begin{pmatrix}\ y_1 & y_2\\ \ y_1' & \ y_2' \end{pmatrix}=x^3$

But computing it with Abel's formula I get:

$W\left(y_1, y_2\right)\left(x\right)=W\left(y_1, y_2\right)\left(1\right)e^{-∫_1^x \frac{-3}{t}dt}\,=|x|^3$

Why there is a difference? Should I omit the absolute value? Am I allowed do that? Why? Abel's formula is supposed to work in any case, isn't it?

Comment: Note that if you have $x<0$, then the integration interval includes $t=0$ where the integrand is singular. That should suggests that Abel's formula as written is probably only sensible for $x>0$. Additionally, $|x|^3$ is a solution to the ODE; what it isn't is a smooth solution (third derivative doesn't exist).

Comment: So how should I do it properly? Is there a way with Able's formula (maybe with a more general version that I'm not aware of) to get the real Wronskian? ($x^3$)